# how to convert column titles from int to str in python

Tags: python-3.x

I imported a file from spss, (sav file), however, the titles of my columns 
appear as integers instead of strings. Is there a way to fix it? Below is the code I used....I would apreciate any help!

```
   import fnmatch  
   import sys # import sys
   import os
   import pandas as pd #pandas importer
   import savReaderWriter as spss # to import file from SPSS
   import io #importing io
   import codecs #to resolve the UTF-8 unicode
   with spss.SavReader('file_name.sav') as reader: #Should I add "Np"
        records = reader.all()
    with codecs.open('file_name.sav', "r",encoding='utf-8', errors='strict') 
   as fdata: # Not sure if the problems resides on this line
       df = pd.DataFrame(records)
   df.head()
```

Wondering whether there is a way to actually convert the titles from numbers to strings. It has happened as if it were excel, but excel has an easy fix for that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After you have created the DataFrame, you can use `df.columns = df.columns.map(str)` to change the column headers to strings.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Farhan, after I added your suggestion, the titles still show as numbers. Any thoughts?

Comment: They might still show as numbers, but they have been converted to strings in the background. The output of `df.columns.map(type)` will show you the types of the values. They should all be `<class 'str'>` after executing the line above.